# Using CorePlot with OSX for OSX App

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, core-plot

Some background: I'm making a Obj-C project for some numerical analysis, and want to add a graph. I found core-plot, and had no problem adding the framework and QuartzCore frameworks to my project.

My question now is how to actually utilise it - I have a project with an interface through Interface Builder (MainMenu.xib), an AppDelegate and another class used for modelling the mathematics. I have searched the internet and can only find tutorials for its use within iOS, which isn't what I'm doing - and I don't understand how to convert that to OSX.

I had assumed that I would add a custom view to the MainMenu.xib and link that to a new property using someting along the lines of

```
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSView *graph;
```

Although now that I look at it, putting a NSView object inside a NSObject interface seems silly.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Update 1: So I changed my code to

```
@property (assign) IBOutlet CPTGraphHostingView *graph;
```

And changed the property of the custom view to the same, CPTGraphHostingView. The two are now linked, and I have an outlet called "graph" to play with. The challenge is now putting a graph into that space.

Thanks again!

Comment: `IBOutlet`s are made exactly to reference `NSView`s (and other objects) from your controller objects, so nothing silly about that in and of itself. And in simple apps, the app delegate does often have a controller role.

Comment: Core Plot includes several example apps that show how to do this. Look at the Mac version of CPTTestApp for several simple examples.

Comment: Reading through now, I thought most of the examples were iOS based. I presume controller.h / .m => appDelegate.h / .m in the latter versions of XCode?